# Raw and Keyword in subfields

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I created an index with this mapping :

```
 "movies2": {
    "aliases": {},
    "mappings": {
      "movie": {
        "properties": {
          "fields": {
            "properties": {
              "actors": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {"raw": {"type": "keyword"}}
              },
              "directors": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {"raw": {"type": "keyword"}}
              },
              "genres": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {"raw": {"type": "keyword"}}
              },
```

But later when I tried to check the mapping with :
http://localhost:9200/movies2/?pretty

I found out that the mapping was converted to :

```
 "genres": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {"keyword": {"type": "keyword"}}


      },
```

I am using ElasticSearch 7.0 . Is the "raw" keyword not used anymore? Is it the default behaviour to convert it to "keyword" when we create an index?

Regards,

Comment: No it won't be converted. If you were able to create the index successfully then the sub-field should be `raw`. Are you sure you are checking the correct index?

Comment: @NishantSaini yes, apparently .raw is replaced by .keyword in recent ElasticSearch versions.  https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-elasticsearch/issues/466  . But still need confirmation...